# How to choose w1 in Induced Ordered Weighted Aggregating Operator Algorithm?

Tags: matlab, trust

In the actual algorithm it is actually give as,

> calculate b(1): b1[(m-1)*beta+1-m*b1]^m = [(m-1)beta]^m-1[(m-1)beta-m)b1+1]

How do I decide the value for b1?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the other values (m, beta)?
Then you could use the solving tool, to get the value for b1:

```
    b(1)=solve('function','variable');
```

where in your case you insert your whole function as function and b1 as variable.

Otherwise you should maybe clarify your question, what are you exactly looking for

Comment: the algorithm is based on OWA operator, we use this alg to calculate the weight vector and we give m and beta as input, where m is "no of weights" and beta is the "magnifying factor. Now I dont know how to select or calculate the value of b(1) or b1.

Comment: refer algorithm 3 in this http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6475238

Comment: Didn't have the time read the paper, but as far as I understand you, b1 is your only unknown variable in the equalation. So you have to search for a value of b1 such that the equalation holds. This is exactly what the solve() function in matlab does. The output (at least if there is a numeric solution) then is the b1 you are looking for. Please comment, if you have any problems regarding the inputs for solve().